# Why can't I overwrite self in the Integer class?

Tags: ruby, class, metaprogramming

I want to be able to write `number.incr`, like so:

`num = 1; num.incr; num
 #=> 2`

The error I'm seeing states:
`Can't change the value of self`

If that's true, how do bang! methods work?

Comment: bang methods (on other classes) generally mutate state of an object, not change the object itself. Fixnum has no state, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You cannot change the value of self

An object is a [class pointer and a set of instance methods](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/65a5162/ruby.h#L218-226) (note that this link is an old version of Ruby, because its dramatically simpler, and thus better for explanatory purposes).

"Pointing" at an object means you have a variable which stores the object's location in memory. Then to do anything with the object, you first go to the location in memory (we might say "follow the pointer") to get the object, and then do the thing (e.g. invoke a method, set an ivar).

All Ruby code everywhere is executing in the context of some object. This is where your instance variables get saved, it's where Ruby looks for methods that don't have a receiver (e.g. `$stdout` is the receiver in `$stdout.puts "hi"`, and the current object is the receiver in `puts "hi"`). Sometimes you need to do something with the current object. The way to work with objects is through variables, but what variable points at the current object? There isn't one. To fill this need, the keyword `self` is provided.

`self` acts like a variable in that it points at the location of the current object. But it is not like a variable, because you can't assign it new value. If you could, the code after that point would suddenly be operating on a different object, which is confusing and has no benefits over just using a variable.

Also remember that the object is tracked by variables which store memory addresses. What is `self = 2` supposed to mean? Does it only mean that the current code operates as if it were invoked `2`? Or does it mean that all variables pointing at the old object now have their values updated to point at the new one? It isn't really clear, but the former unnecessarily introduces an identity crisis, and the latter is prohibitively expensive and introduce situations where it's unclear what is correct (I'll go into that a bit more below).

### You cannot mutate Fixnums

[Some objects](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/8341ca059af1dee3348b496f47d2c0ff413e0fda/include/ruby/ruby.h#L396-405) are special at the C level in Ruby (false, true, nil, fixnums, and symbols).

Variables pointing at them don't actually store a memory location. Instead, the address itself stores the type and identity of the object. Wherever it matters, Ruby checks to see if it's a special object (e.g. when [looking up an instance variable](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/8341ca059af1dee3348b496f47d2c0ff413e0fda/variable.c#L1100)), and then extracts the value from it.

So there isn't a spot in memory where the object `123` is stored. Which means `self` contains the idea of Fixnum `123` rather than a memory address like usual. As with variables, it will get checked for and handled specially when necessary.

Because of this, you cannot mutate the object itself (though it appears they keep [a special global variable](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a161f1243550930a38028d58ed6d5f2ae9b6a38b/variable.c#L815) to allow you to set instance variables on things like Symbols).

Why are they doing all of this? To improve performance, I assume. A number stored in a register is just a series of bits (typically 32 or 64), which means there are hardware instructions for things like addition and multiplication. That is to say the ALU, is wired to perform these operations in a single clock cycle, rather than writing the algorithms with software, which would take many orders of magnitude longer. By storing them like this, they avoid the cost of storing and looking the object in memory, and they gain the advantage that they can directly add the two pointers using hardware. Note, however, that there are still some additional costs in Ruby, that you don't have in C (e.g. checking for overflow and converting result to Bignum).

### Bang methods

You can put a bang at the end of any method. It doesn't require the object to change, it's just that people usually try to warn you when you're doing something that could have unexpected side-effects.

```
class C
  def initialize(val)
    @val = val         # => 12
  end                  # => :initialize

  def bang_method!
    "My val is: #{@val}"  # => "My val is: 12"
  end                     # => :bang_method!
end                       # => :bang_method!

c = C.new 12    # => #<C:0x007fdac48a7428 @val=12>
c.bang_method!  # => "My val is: 12"
c               # => #<C:0x007fdac48a7428 @val=12>
```

Also, there are no bang methods on integers, It wouldn't fit with the paradigm

```
Fixnum.instance_methods.grep(/!$/)  # => [:!]

# Okay, there's one, but it's actually a boolean negation
1.!  # => false

# And it's not a Fixnum method, it's an inherited boolean operator
1.method(:!).owner  # => BasicObject

# In really, you call it this way, the interpreter translates it
!1  # => false
```

### Alternatives

- Make a wrapper object: I'm not going to advocate this one, but it's the closest to what you're trying to do. Basically create your own class, which is mutable, and then make it look like an integer. There's a great blog post walking through this at http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/rklemme/019-Complete_Numeric_Class.html it will get you 95% of the way there
- Don't depend directly on the value of a Fixnum: I can't give better advice than this without knowing what you're trying to do / why you feel this is a need.

---

Also, you should show your code when you ask questions like this. I misunderstood how you were approaching it for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply impossible to change `self` to another object. `self` is the receiver of the message send. There can be only one.

> If that's true, how do bang! methods work?

The bang (`!`) is simply part of the method name. It has absolutely no special meaning whatsoever. It is a convention among Ruby programmers to name surprising variants of less surprising methods with a bang, but that's just that: a convention.