# Fixnum object does not change value after being increased

Tags: ruby, object, addition, fixnum

I just started learning Ruby, and encounterd this 2 functions:

```
def increase(n)
    n = n + 1
    return n
end

def add_element(array, item)
    array << item
end
```

When I tried increase(n) with n = 5

```
c = 5
p10.increase(c)
print("c is #{c}\n")
print("c.class is #{c.class}\n")
--> c is 5
--> c.class is Fixnum
```

Value of c does not change after being increased inside increase(n)

When I tried to change the content of an array arr = [1,2,3,4] with add_element, arr does change.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
p10.add_element(arr, 5)
print("array is #{arr}\n")
--> array is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So if everything in Ruby is object, why arr changes its value, but c ( a Fixnum object ) does not change its value?

Your thought is appreciated. :) Thanks

Comment: Not all objects are mutable. Numbers, as you found out, are not. If they were, the outcome of `1+2`  could be anything.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083650/why-cant-i-overwrite-self-in-the-integer-class and warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21411269/5239030

Comment: What is `p10`? .

Answer (score 4):

There are "special" objects in Ruby that are not mutable. `Fixnum` is one of them (others are booleans, `nil`, symbols, other numerics). Ruby is also pass by value.

`n = n + 1` does not modify `n`, it reassigns a local variable in `increase`'s scope.
Since `Fixnum` isn't mutable, there is no method you could use to change its value, unlike an array, which you can mutate with multiple methods, `<<` being one of them.

`add_element` explicitly modifies the passed object with `<<`. If you change the method body to

```
array = array + [item]
```

then the output in your second example will be `array is [1, 2, 3, 4]` as it's a mere reassignment of a local variable.